# Is Abine TACO comparable to NoScript addon in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, security, privacy, noscript

As someone who is trying to be security conscious on the web, I've setup Firefox to use the Tor network and NoScript, among other plugins.

However, I've found NoScript to be such a pain since I have to manually set permissions for each site I visit. More frustrating is that some sites *still don't work* even after I "temporarily allow all" in NoScript.

Therefore, I have temporarily disabled the NoScript addon in my copy of Firefox 6, and am considering the Abine TACO package.

TACO seems very comprehensive, but:

1. While it doesn't block all scripts at a site, are TACO's anti
   tracking features comparable to how NoScript would block tracking
   attempts?
2. Are there any good reviews on the effectiveness and safety of
   using Abine TACO? (my preliminary search did not show any useful
   results)